# Change a number to a word in only 1 column

Tags: r

I want to change 0 to Male and 1 to Female in only 1 column of my data set.

```
Sex Age        LHUM RHUM    LRAD
0   40-50       0   1        0
1   50+         1   1        1
0   30-50       0   0        1
0   25-30       0   0        0
1   50+         0   0        0
1   30-40       0   0        0
0   30-50       0   0        0
```

Comment: Fyi, select and "CTRL+K" for block code; or there's a button on top of the editor; or put four spaces at the beginning of the line.

Comment: Do you have a character/factor class for `Sex` column?  The description says values are '0' and '1', while the data shows '-0' and '-1'

Comment: the values are 0 and 1…i added the - by accident when i was trying to make the list. new to the site

Comment: `?gsub` will tell you one of the many ways to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `plyr` package has a function `mapvalues` for making such replacements:

```
library(plyr)
df1$Sex <- mapvalues(df1$Sex, from = c(0,1), to = c("Male", "Female"))
```

Comment: @Jackie glad it helped. If your question is answered you can click the check mark so that others know it is resolved.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
df1$Sex<-ifelse(df1$Sex==0,'Male','Female')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
 df1$Sex <- c('Male', 'Female')[df1$Sex +1L]
 df1$Sex
 #[1] "Male"   "Female" "Male"   "Male"   "Female" "Female" "Male"
```

Or

```
df1$Sex <-  as.vector(factor(df1$Sex, labels=c('Male', 'Female')))
```

If the values are 0 and -1

```
 df1$Sex <- c('Male', 'Female')[ (-1*(df1$Sex))+1L]
```

#### data

```
 df1 <- structure(list(Sex = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), 
 Age =  c("40-50", 
"50+", "30-50", "25-30", "50+", "30-40", "30-50"), LHUM = c(0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), RHUM = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
LRAD = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("Sex", 
"Age", "LHUM", "RHUM", "LRAD"), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: @Frank Thanks, I didn't notice it earlier.

Comment: hi akrun when i input the 1st value it makes everything NA

Comment: @Jackie If your column is numeric, it should work.  Can you check the `str(yourdata)` and see if it is 'numeric' column

Comment: @Jackie Can you confirm whether the column is 'character' class?